# Php login not executing else

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a login form using PHP and MySQL. However, I am running into an error when I type in the wrong login info.

```
<?php

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    if($result)
      {
       header('Location: supplementsstore.php');
      }
    else
      {
        header('Location: logon.php');
      }
    }

?>
```

The `if` works as it's supposed to, but it does not do the `else` statement. 
I have tried changing else to `!$result` but that didn't work either.

Comment: *"i am running in to an error"* - Being? Take your pick of 1001 possible reasons. *Totally unclear what you're asking*.

Comment: Why are you doing `if($result)`?

Comment: What is $result we need more details

Comment: Whatever your mistake is, the `exit` is missing for guarantee.

Comment: If you are inside that loop, that already means if($result) is true, so your else statement is unreachable.

Comment: I am not an expert at PHP, so correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't `if($result)' just test if `$result` was not null. Try extracting the data from the SQL result, and comparing it against user input

Comment: `(null !== $result)` tests if `$result` is not `null`. `if ( ... )` just checks for something being truthy (`null` isn't truthy but falsy in PHP so you're not far off with the `null` example).

Comment: Do the comparison against the database and store the result of the comparison into another variable. Then *after* the comparison place the if. That should help you keep things separated which will make it more easy for you.

Answer (score 2):

If `if($result)` were to evaluate to false the while loop would never be entered.

So try:

```
if( count($row) > 0 )
```

rather than

```
if($result){}
```

Comment: I'd never take that stab in the dark, even with the biggest and longest knife around. But, you may be right. Let's see what the OP has to say ;-) Could be a lucky shiv.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
header('Location: supplementsstore.php');
}
else
{
header('Location: logon.php');
}
```